# Switching to non-root user and running command in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to switch to the "apache" user in my Python script and run a command.  I have tried quite a few combinations of other answers, and cant quite get it working.  Here are the things I have tried -

This one causes my terminal to hang -

```
command = "sudo su - apache && touch ~/testfile.txt"    
for email in emailList:
   client = paramiko.SSHClient()
   client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())    
   privatekeyfile = '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa2'
   username ="myuser"
   mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)
   client.connect(hostname='123.456.11.11',username=username, pkey = mykey)

   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
   gracefulout = stdout.read()
   print gracefulout
```

Changing the command to - 
`command = "sudo su - apache -c 'touch testfile.txt'"` causes it to do nothing.

Variations like `sudo -u apache; whoami` cause nothing to be outputted.  `subprocess.call([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` causes either nothing to be outputted or the shell to hang.

Also tried this -

```
   ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", HOST, COMMAND],
      shell=True,
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
   if result == []:
     error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
     print sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
   else:
     print result
```

And received the error -

```
ERROR: ['usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]\n', '           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]\n', '           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]\n', '           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]\n', '           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]\n', '           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]\n', '           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]\n', '           [user@]hostname [command]\n']
```

What is a way for me to switch to a different (non-root) user in python and run a command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, we fixed this by running the following command instead -

```
   command = 'php -r "print json_encode(array('test@test.com'));" | /usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/home/me/drush_aliases @'+alias+'.'+env+' --root=/var/www/html/docroot vset --format=json update_notify_emails -'

   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
   drushoutput = stdout.read()
   print(drushoutput)
   client.close()
```